# How should I optimize my cycleGAN spectral denoising network based on the generator and discriminator loss plots I got?

Tags: tf.keras

As i mentioned in the title, i'm trying to optimize a cycleGAN based denoising network to realize the ransformation of spectral profiles in shaded and illuminated areas. There are both 1000 unpaired spectral curves of 64 bands for each of the shaded and illuminated regions(datasets named TrainA and TrainB).
Here are some parameters i set in my model:

```
optimizer_d=Adam(learning_rate=2e-5,beta_1=0.5,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=None)
optimizer_g=Adam(learning_rate=2e-4,beta_1=0.5,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=None)
epochs=100
batch_size=1
```

here are the network structure of discriminator and generator:

```
def build_generator(self):
    """U-Net Generator"""
    def conv1d(layer_input, filters, f_size=4):
        d = Conv1D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')(layer_input)
        d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
        d = InstanceNormalization(axis=2)(d)
        return d

    def deconv1d(layer_input, skip_input, filters, f_size=4, dropout_rate=0):
        u = UpSampling1D(size=2)(layer_input)
        u = Conv1D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(u)
        if dropout_rate:
            u = Dropout(dropout_rate)(u)
        u = InstanceNormalization(axis=2)(u)
        u = Concatenate()([u, skip_input])
        return u

    # Image input
    d0 = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    # Downsampling
    d1 = conv1d(d0, self.gf)
    d2 = conv1d(d1, self.gf*2)
    d3 = conv1d(d2, self.gf*4)
    d4 = conv1d(d3, self.gf*8)
    # Upsampling
    u1 = deconv1d(d4, d3, self.gf*4)
    u2 = deconv1d(u1, d2, self.gf*2)
    u3 = deconv1d(u2, d1, self.gf)

    u4 = UpSampling1D(size=2)(u3)
    output_img = Conv1D(self.channels, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding='same', activation='tanh')(u4)

    return Model(d0, output_img)

def build_discriminator(self):

    def d_layer(layer_input, filters, f_size=4, normalization=True):
        """Discriminator layer"""
        d = Conv1D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')(layer_input)
        d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
        if normalization:
            d = InstanceNormalization()(d)
        return d

    img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

    d1 = d_layer(img, self.df, normalization=False)
    d2 = d_layer(d1, self.df*2)
    d3 = d_layer(d2, self.df*4)
    # d4 = d_layer(d3, self.df*8)

    validity = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding='same')(d3)

    return Model(img, validity)
```

here are the loss functions of netG and netD:

```
# discriminators:
dA_loss_real = self.d_A.train_on_batch(imgs_A, valid)
dA_loss_fake = self.d_A.train_on_batch(fake_A, fake)
dA_loss = 0.5 * np.add(dA_loss_real, dA_loss_fake)
dB_loss_real = self.d_B.train_on_batch(imgs_B, valid)
dB_loss_fake = self.d_B.train_on_batch(fake_B, fake)
dB_loss = 0.5 * np.add(dB_loss_real, dB_loss_fake)
# Total disciminator loss
d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(dA_loss, dB_loss)

# combined:
self.combined = Model(inputs=[img_A, img_B],
                        outputs=[ valid_A, valid_B,      
                                  reconstr_A, reconstr_B,
                                  img_A_id, img_B_id ])
self.combined.compile(loss=['mse', 'mse',
                            'mae', 'mae',
                            'mae', 'mae'],
                    loss_weights=[  1, 1,
                                    10, 10,
                                    1, 1 ],
                    optimizer=optimizer_g)
```

Here is Loss curves of netG_loss and netD_loss:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dmbD.png)
and here are the results of validation datas:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6zpu.png)
the loss of netD increases very slow, almost flat; and the spectral conversion is very poor. What should i try optimizing my network? I'm a novice in GAN networks and I'm not sure what I should do to improve the performance of the models. Should i increase the learning_rate of net_D? Or i should increase the batch_size? I will add any info or code you need to help guide me!